# Resque fails when run with God - JavaScript run-time?

Tags: javascript, ruby, resque, god, execjs

I'm trying to deploy a simple Rails app with a couple of Resque workers. Since I need the workers to run in the background I'm using God to manage them. When running the workers from the command line it runs just fine:

```
QUEUE=* /var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake -f /var/www/billtune/current/Rakefile environment rescue:work
```

But when they are run by God it seems that the processes keep crashing. Looking at the log files it seems to be related to execjs:

```
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/current/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/billtune/current/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/var/www/billtune/current/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How come a JavaScript runtime is missing when running by God, but not missing when running directly??

For the sake of completeness I'm also attaching the relevant God file:

```
rails_env   = ENV['RAILS_ENV']  || "production"
rails_root  = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/..'
num_workers = rails_env == 'production' ? 2 : 1
puts "rails_root=" + rails_root

num_workers.times do |num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.dir      = "#{rails_root}"
    w.name     = "resque-#{num}"
    w.group    = 'resque'
    w.interval = 30.seconds
    w.env      = {"QUEUE"=>"*", "RAILS_ENV"=>rails_env}
    w.start    = "bundle exec rake -f #{rails_root}/Rakefile environment resque:work"
    w.log      = "#{rails_root}/log/resque-#{num}.log"
    w.err_log  = "#{rails_root}/log/resque_error-#{num}.log"

#    w.uid = 'git'
#    w.gid = 'git'

    # restart if memory gets too high
    w.transition(:up, :restart) do |on|
      on.condition(:memory_usage) do |c|
        c.above = 350.megabytes
        c.times = 2
      end
    end

    # determine the state on startup
    w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
      end
    end

    # determine when process has finished starting
    w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end

      # failsafe
      on.condition(:tries) do |c|
        c.times = 5
        c.transition = :start
        c.interval = 5.seconds
      end
    end

    # start if process is not running
    w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it starts up the rails application and i guess you are using some asset stuff in there that requires a javascript compiler.

Comment: @shaimo are you sure that god is running in write environment I mean try giving user and guid god since god most start with sudo it would run the code in sudo mode hence the binary wont be available in sudo user

Comment: @Viren - thanks for your reply. Indeed God is currently root user and group. What do you suggest I change it to? Doesn't it need the root permissions in order to start and stop processes?

Comment: @phoet - Thanks. So how come it doesn't require it when running it from the command line?

Comment: @shaimo define the `uid` and `guid` in `god config` and god would run your rake with that user and you would not have issue of missing gem then